# How to set double text line on Column Headers in Vaadin Table

Tags: vaadin

I need to do a table in Vaadin but the text in the column headers are too long, so the table enable the horizontal scrolling and I don't want that.

Is there any way to put those column headers in two lines like maybe increasing the heigth of the headers to avoid the scrolling and get all the information in the table?

Comment: There is no code. It's a simple table in Vaadin with some columns

Comment: Vaadin version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this into your scss:

```
.myTheme .v-table-header {
    color: #fff;
    background: #4455aa;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: normal;
  }
```

**Compile** it, clear browser **cache**, and then simply **add style** to your table.

```
table.addStyleName("myTheme");
```

Comment: Is there a non-css way?

Comment: using Vaadin v7